# Connect two apps via custom subdomain on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, dns, subdomain

I have two separate rails apps. I'd like to connect them by simply linking them in the header. One is, for example, http://example.com and I'd like the other to be, for example http://different.example.com.

I added the relevant domain to the first heroku app and it's working. I created a subdomain with my domain host, setting the host CNAME to the previously referenced "different." I then attempted to add the subdomain to the heroku app by running the command:

$ heroku domains:add different.example.com

Despite that, it's not working. Any thoughts on what I've done wrong? I followed the instructions from my domain host and on heroku's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you made a recent change, it's possible that your connection to the Internet or ISP might be serving you a cached, old version of where you want to go.

Try accessing the site from another entry point such as through a third party like https://crossbrowsertesting.com and then you can rule out this possibility.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I got it working. Took it a couple days to kick in for some reason.